# Can't debug generic ESP32 Dev Module with Arduino IDE

Tags: esp32, arduino-ide

I'm newbie with Arduino IDE.

Arduino IDE version:

```
Version: 2.2.1
Date: 2023-08-31T14:35:44.802Z (1 month ago)
CLI Version: 0.34.0

Copyright © 2023 Arduino SA
```

I use a generic ESP32-WROOM-32 dev module like this:

[image: generic ESP32-WROOM-32 dev module]

I had board manager ESP32 and additionnal board manager `https://raw.githubusercontent.com/espressif/arduino-esp32/gh-pages/package_esp32_index.json`:

[image]

I can compile and upload, but when I want debug, I got this message:
[image]

I don't understand what's happen.

Board information is:

```
BN: Unknown board
VID: 0x10C4
PID: 0xEA60
SN: 0001
```

Why Arduino IDE want use gdb for arm, my ESP2 is xtensa ?

My example (works fine):

```
int lightStatus = 0;

#define LED_GPIO 4

void setup() {
  pinMode(LED_GPIO , OUTPUT);
}

void turn_on(int l) {
  digitalWrite(l, HIGH);
}

void turn_off(int l) {
  digitalWrite(l, LOW);
}

void loop() {
  if (lightStatus == 0) {
    lightStatus = 1;
    turn_on(LED_GPIO);
  } else {
    lightStatus = 0;
    turn_off(LED_GPIO);
  }

  delay(1000);
}
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

The problem you mentioned is due to some interrupted processes during installation of esp32 boards, I would suggest you remove esp32 board configuration completely from
**AppData** folder or by **ArduinoIDE** directly, and then **Reinstall ESP32 boards** with uninterrupted internet connection.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I do this 3 times, but I had always same error.